# How to use Ramda to find matching object in Array by key value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

**[Ramda REPL example](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20port%20%3D%20%5B%7Bticker%3A%22aa%22%7D%2C%20%7Bticker%3A%22bb%22%7D%5D%0A%0Avar%20ticker%20%3D%20%7Bticker%3A%22aa%22%7D%0A%0Avar%20exist%20%3D%20R.find%28R.propEq%28%27ticker%27%2C%20ticker%29%2C%20port%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28exist%29%0A)**

```
var portfolio = [{ticker: "aa"},  {ticker: "bb"}];

var ticker = {ticker:"aa"};

var exist = R.find(R.propEq('ticker', ticker), portfolio)

console.log(exist)
```

Currently this is giving me *undefined*, however [R.propEq](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#propEq) should find the matching object by key `ticker` in `port` I thought?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you say, you can solve it by passing in the key to [`propEq`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#propEq):

```
R.find(R.propEq('ticker', 'aa'), port)
```

Another option is to use the [`eqProps`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqProps) function, which tests if two objects match for the named key:

```
R.find(R.eqProps('ticker', ticker), port)
```

You can see the **[first](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20port%20%3D%20%5B%7Bticker%3A%22aa%22%2C%20id%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7Bticker%3A%22bb%22%2C%20id%3A%202%7D%5D%0A%0AR.find%28R.propEq%28%27ticker%27%2C%20%27aa%27%29%2C%20port%29%0A)** or **[second](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20port%20%3D%20%5B%7Bticker%3A%22aa%22%2C%20id%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7Bticker%3A%22bb%22%2C%20id%3A%202%7D%5D%0Aconst%20ticker%20%3D%20%7Bticker%3A%22aa%22%7D%0A%0AR.find%28R.eqProps%28%27ticker%27%2C%20ticker%29%2C%20port%29%0A)** version in the Ramda REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Ah it was a simple mistake, I forgot to pass in the exact key from the ticker object.

`R.propEq('ticker', ticker.ticker)`

This is how I now solve my problem in my app:

```
const exists = R.find(R.propEq('ticker', this.ticker.ticker));
this.inPortfolio = !!exists(portTickers);
console.log('this.inPortfolio', this.inPortfolio)
// True or false
```